# После выполнения if выполняется else

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

Проблема: else выполняется в любом случае, даже если срабатывает if.

```
print('1 - standart hour\nEnter - custom timer')
i = input()

if i==1 :
    loc_tm = 3600
    
else:
    print('sleep time?')
    loc_tm = float(input())
    loc_tm = loc_tm * 60
```

Comment: В i записывается строка, она никогда не бывает равна числу 1

Comment: Не уверены в коде, отладьте его, хотя бы через `print`: `print(i, type(i), i == 1)`. Добавили бы что-то такое и сразу стало бы понятно в чем проблема :)

Comment: Прошу прощения за бесполезный вопрос, был сильно невнимателен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `i` лежит строка, а вы её сравнивает с числом

Вам надо либо превратить `i`  в число, либо сравнивать с строкой:

```
i = int(input())
```

либо

```
if i == "1":
```